# Creating small scale application like Blender?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, blender

I have been thinking about my final year project topic and to be honest I want to create something GREAAAT like many others. I know C,C++,Java and Python (Python is getting quite popular these days).. I want to create a small-scale application like Blender (graphics rendering software) any tips for me? I prefer using OpenGL and it's shading language rather than Direct3D since it is open-source.

Tell me the stuffs I should know to pull this off and also if the combination of python and OpenGL a good choice for this application ?

Comment: Blender is open source. There are a couple of other open source 3D graphics programs that aren't as big, so take a look at their source code.

Comment: @Blender is open source?

Comment: Small scale?  *Blender*?  What's your point of reference for *large* scale?

Comment: @Elazar: You can get a [tarball](http://www.blender.org/download/source-code/) or check it out [with Subversion](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/).

Comment: I tried to mean a small-scale version of blender... I didn't mean Blender is small scale :P :P

Comment: Blender or any half decent 3D modeling/animation suite has a large number of features, which you don't seem to be aware of. You're not going to do "something like Blender" on your own in under a year. Or ten. I suggest you find out what exactly you want to do first.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a small-scale application like Blender (graphics rendering software) any tips for me?

Yes: Readjust your perception of software size/complexity. I occasionally contribute (TBH, it's been years since I submitted something substantial) to Blender and over the years it turned into a mighty suite. But the codebase is just as large.

Comment: I meant a small-scale version of Blender maybe.. :)

Answer (score 0):

A small object-viewer should definitely be possible. That's something you can build and add features upon, depending on how much time is left. I would do the visualization and movement in your scene first, then some basic interactions with your objects (translating, rotating, etc.). The final step would be adding tools (edit polygons, sculpt, etc.). If you are fit enough in C++, OpenGL and Software-Architecture on a larger scale it should be doable.

Comment: thank you :) I am good at C++ however someone told me Python is a bit easier for GUI design and sometimes more effective than C++.. So, I might use python as well :)

Comment: May I ask if you have done a GUI-Project before? If you want an OpenGL view along with some controls beside it I'd suggest you use something like Qt. Exposing an interface of your GUI-Functionalities to python just adds another layer of complexity, and it is usually only done if you want your application to be easily extensible by others.

Comment: I haven't used Qt before, is it compatible with OpenGL ? I have done GUI, but it was database related , not really graphical.. Will check out Qt.